# I have confusion about when using -t in git checkout and when not using

Tags: git

I don't actually get the point about what are exactly differences between:
git checkout branchName and git checkout -t branchName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-t` (or `--track`) option is only used when creating a new (local) branch that should be related to a particular branch on the remote (via a particular remote tracking ref).

Even then the option is often unnecessary because of a shorthand approach built into git for the most common case: creating a local branch to track a remote branch of the same name from a remote[1].  For that case, you can just say

```
git checkout myBranch
```

and because the local branch doesn't already exist but exactly one remote tracking ref `remotes/*/myBranch` *does* exist, git figure you want to create the new branch and track the remote branch.

If the shorthand won't work, say because you have `remotes/origin/myBranch` and `remotes/upstream/myBranch`, then you can specify which to track.

```
git checkout -t remotes/origin/myBranch
```

If the shorthand won't work because you want a different branch name locally, you can combine `-t` with -b`.

```
git checkout -t -b localBranch remotes/origin/myBranch
```

---

[1] as long as exactly one remote has a branch of the given name